# After Linear Regression with Ridge Regressor - which solver was used?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

Scikit-learn linear regression class "Ridge regression" has the parameter "solver" to define which solver should be used.

If it is set to "auto" can I find out which solver was actually used in hindsight?

According to the _RidgeBase parent class which `Ridge` inherits, the `solver` field should be set to the actual solver used [[GitHub]](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841d57e8b5f6b2a570312e9d832e69debc/sklearn/linear_model/_ridge.py#L563), so I'd expect the value to be the one afterward. But it if I print the solver afterward it still returns "auto"

```
regressor = Ridge(alpha = 0.1, fit_intercept = False, normalize = False)
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(x_test)
print(regressor.solver)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems by looking at their [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b9692a6becca64daeac28c6156e847f2989ce45e/sklearn/linear_model/_ridge.py#L378) that the solver used for your model is not stored in any property for you to access.

However, this is in their [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b9692a6becca64daeac28c6156e847f2989ce45e/sklearn/linear_model/_ridge.py#L385), hope it helps.

```
if solver == 'auto':
    if return_intercept:
        # only sag supports fitting intercept directly
        solver = "sag"
    elif not sparse.issparse(X):
        solver = "cholesky"
    else:
        solver = "sparse_cg"
```

Comment: Regarding to the [line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841d57e8b5f6b2a570312e9d832e69debc/sklearn/linear_model/_ridge.py#L563) you linked, they update **solver** which is a local variable. Do not confuse it with **_self_.solver**.

Comment: ah okey thank you for that. I missed the tiny missing "self."